# HybridAuth fails on login for Facebook app reviewer

Tags: facebook, authentication, hybridauth

I'm using HybridAuth 3.0.0rc6 for [a website of mine](https://theplacesihavebeen.com). Besides allowing users to login with Facebook, Twitter or LinkedIn, I also use HybridAuth to pick up the friends/connections of a user, in case other users of my site are friends of the current user logging in.

This works fine, or so I thought.

With the upcoming Facebook changes, if you want to use "user_friends", you have to go through the Facebook app review. My reviewer did not accept my site, for the simple reason that, for him, the login button doesn't work. It produces an error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: pagedList [...] /Facebook.php on line 199.

Here's the screenshot the reviewer sent me:

[image]

This is the offending code:

```
do {
    $response = $this->apiRequest($apiUrl);

    $data = new Data\Collection($response);

    if (! $data->exists('data')) {
        throw new UnexpectedApiResponseException('Provider API returned an unexpected response.');
    }

    if ($data->filter('data')->isEmpty()) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($data->filter('data')->toArray() as $item) {
        $contacts[] = $this->fetchUserContact($item);
    }

    if ($data->filter('paging')->exists('next')) {
        $apiUrl = $data->filter('paging')->get('next');

        $pagedList = true;
    } else {
        $pagedList = false;
    }
} while ($pagedList); //This is line 199
```

I can of course turn off Notices, but I would like to understand, first, how the variable pagedList can be undefined. After all, the if-clause always defines it, and, second, how it's possible that I have never seen this error when logging in using Facebook.

Comment: If you hit the continue $pagedList is not set.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I looked with my nose.